# remove external css properties using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have html like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>date</td>
  <td>name</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>aug</td>
  <td>tr</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and this is the css external @media queries(max-width:768px)

```
td{
 display:block
}
```

How can I remove the `display: block` in external css using jQuery?
I tried this but I think its only working on inline css

```
$("td").css({"display":""});
```

I cant remove the `display: block` in external css cause I need it in another pages

I tried to read this [also](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) but only removing the display was the best solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you want to hide? use `.hide()`

Comment: and I guess, this is not correct {"display":""}. You should set one of the "display" values not ""

Comment: @Pasha yes but i not to remove the `display` itself in just one page or override it.

Comment: that page has an id or class, which is it ? or what does that table on that page have in particular from other pages ?

Comment: @MihaiT i need to maintain the TD's as what is it when in mobile

Comment: you said that you want to remove the `display:block` , only on a specific page . Which page is that ? does it have a particular class or id ? or any other particularity that differs from other pages?

Comment: Why do it with jQuery? why not just give those cells a class and then overwrite your media query as it appears that none of the jQuery answers seem to work for you

Comment: @MihaiT it dont have a specific `id` or `class`

Comment: @Pete so Im going to remove this `td{display:block}` and put a class name in all td that gonna need the `display:block` like this `.hasDisplay{display:block}`?

Comment: no do the opposite, only add a class to the ones you want to remain as a table-cell (as you said it was only on one page) - `.stay-table { display:table-cell; }` and put this after that other `td` style in the media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say the page where you want to change the `display:block` style, doesn't have anything in particular that could differentiate it from other pages like an id or class. Or some wrapper outside the table etc. ,then you can't specify the style only for that page in particular.

You should know that you cannot just 'delete' styles. You can just overwrite them with other styles. All elements have a bunch of styles set by default. Like `td` have `display:table-cell;visibility:visible;opacity:1` etc. . block elements have `display:block` etc. , see here [css initial values](https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush/blob/master/misc/initial-values.ini)

So what you can do is maybe set a specific class to that table you want to change, and then in css write

```
table:not(.myTable) td {
    display:block;
}
```

And so, the `display:block` style will NOT be applied to the desired table cells and the `td` will stay with default style, `display:table-cell`

You could also write ( if you don't want to change the style you already set )

```
table td {
     display:block;
}
table.myTable td {
      display:table-cell;
}
```

Or there are many possibilities to change/overwrite css styles ( using css or javascript etc. ) , but you can't just 'remove' styles. As i said before, every html element has initial styles set for every property.

**see snippet with CSS**

```css
td {
 display:block;
 color:red;
}
table.myTable td {
 display:table-cell;
 color:blue
}
```

```html
<!-- Table with td display:block-->
<table>
<tr>
<td>aa</td>
<td>bb</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Table with td display:table-cell-->
<table class="myTable">
<tr>
<td>aa</td>
<td>bb</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**overwrite property with JQ**

```js
$("td").css({
  "display": "table-cell",
 "color":"blue"
})
```

```css
td {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table with td display:block-->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>bb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried that also putting another [property values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)  on `display` still hopeless.

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization how did you try to put the other property value ? you need to be as specific as possible, so you can overwrite the style already set. So write a more specific path like `body #content table.myTable td { display:table-cell}` . In worst case scenario use `!important` after the style, but i strongly suggest you avoid using it

Comment: By using jQuery I added another property value on it that listed on that site and `display:table-cell` doesnt work.

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization added 2 examples. 1 with CSS 1 with JQ . one of them should work for you

Comment: I tried that also but it doesnt work trying to change the property values

Comment: that's impossible. Do you have JQ added to your project ? do other JQ scripts work ? what does it say in console and also in the `Styles` section when you select your `td` ? are there some styles crossed over ?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization

Answer (score 1):

You cant change external css property using javascript, but you can override those properties defined in external style sheet. javascript styles takes higher precedence than external style sheet

Comment: How can I override those properties? I used `$("td").css({"display":""});` to override it but still no luck

Comment: That works properly, just check in your console is there any error

Comment: but that code only works on inline css it cant override the external css

Comment: It can override the external css if I put a correct property value of `display` for example `.css({"display":"inline"})` it will override but in my case I need to remove the `display`

Comment: You must specify` key` and `value` pair

Comment: Ye but in my case I need to remove the `display` in that page

Comment: From what `display:block`  to `display:""` it is not possible, how can possible to set empty property in css, is it works, try in inpect element.  it wont work

Comment: Yes but it is the only solution so far I tried to remove the `display:block` in `mozilla firebug` it works

Comment: That is not possible , element should be either `display` `block` or `inline`

Comment: It means you did some thing wrong, even if you didn't assign eny `display` property browser automatically render

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
$("td").css({"display":"table-cell"});
```

Did you try also this?

```
$("td").each(function () {
  this.style.display = '';
});
```

Otherwise you could add a class to override and reset the style to table-cell.

Comment: I tried all `display` property values but still not fixing my problem but by removing the `display` itself it will fix my problem